# Why the same opencl code cannot be run on IMX.6?

Tags: image-processing, buffer, opencl, embedded-linux

We're trying to use OpenCL for some image processing on IMX.6.

We used a already-tested opencl code. In the kernel.cl file, the only opencl thing is

```
int i= get_global_id(0);
int j= get_global_id(1);
```

All other works are based on pure-c language instead of opencl.

And the code runs well on the PC.

However, when we test the code on IMX.6. All of the status shows correct, but we cannot have the correct result.

The read and write buffer function clEnqueueReadBuffer has no problem at all, we tested the uploaded image. BUT the kernel running function doesn't have any result. clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.

Does anyone know why?
By the way, this question is the 2000 question of opencl:)

Here is the whole code:

```
  __kernel void IPM(__global const unsigned char* image_ROI_data, __global unsigned char* IPM_data, __global float* parameter_IPM)
{
float camera_col=parameter_IPM[1];
float camera_row=parameter_IPM[0];

float camera_height=parameter_IPM[2];
float camera_alpha=parameter_IPM[3];
float camera_theta=parameter_IPM[4];

float image_vp=parameter_IPM[5];

float IPM_width=parameter_IPM[6];
float IPM_height=parameter_IPM[7];

int IPM_lineByte=(((int)IPM_width+3)/4)*4;
int image_lineByte=(((int)camera_col+3)/4)*4;

int i= get_global_id(0);
int j= get_global_id(1);

*(IPM_data+((int)IPM_height-j)*IPM_lineByte+i)=0;

float multiple=(float)(IPM_width/20);

// Real x and Real y(they are both meters)
float x=(float)(i-IPM_width/2)/multiple;
float y=(float)(j)/multiple;

// The coordinator in capture image.
float u=(camera_row-1)*(atan(camera_height/sqrt(x*x+y*y))+camera_alpha-camera_theta)/(2*camera_alpha);
float v=(camera_col-1)*(atan(x/y)+camera_alpha)/(2*camera_alpha);

// If the point was in capture image, choose its pixel and fill the image.
// As it is only a ROI so it is u-image_vp
if (((int)u-(int)image_vp)>0 && (int)u<(int)camera_row && v>0 && v<camera_col)
{
    *(IPM_data+((int)IPM_height-j)*IPM_lineByte+i)=
        *(image_ROI_data+((int)u-(int)image_vp)* image_lineByte+(int)v);
}
```

}

Comment: If your target platform is compatible with OpenCL full profile, run simplest vector addition kernel to make sure things are working. If it's ok, attach some of your code to look at, your question is very generic at current moment

Comment: Running on embedded profile? They say most of the capabilities are reduced in this profile. Also it was opencl 1.1 compliant. You PC may have opencl 1.2 capability and higher values.

Comment: @RomanArzumanyan Arzumanyan Thanks for answersing. I've tested the simple vector adding code on the both platform. There was no problem. However, just this code has some problem.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Hi, thanks for answering. I uploaded the whole kernel code, as you can see, they are all in cl1.0...

Comment: The only "suspicion" thing in code I can see is explicit types casting. You may try to use convert class of functions

Comment: What sort of result you do get? No writes at all? Garbage? The kernel fails at enqueueNDRange?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 int i= get_global_id(0); // starts from zero
 int j= get_global_id(1); // this too

 float x=(float)(i-IPM_width/2)  // maybe zero maybe not
 float y=(float)(j)/multiple;    // becomes zero

 float v=(camera_col-1)*(atan(x/y)+camera_alpha)/(2*camera_alpha);
                                ^
                                |
                                |
                               / \
                           division by zero
                 Becomes NaN or INF, and the rest follow.
             Then you get a wrong result originating from this.

  Especially when you use it for pointer calculus:

  *(IPM_data+((int)IPM_height-j)*IPM_lineByte+i)=
    *(image_ROI_data+((int)u-(int)image_vp)* image_lineByte+(int)v);
                                                                 ^
                                                                 |
                                                                 |
                                                                /-\
                                                    gg if "if" body is entered
```

Answer (score 3):

Your Device support only embedded OpenCL profile, which is a subset of full profile, supported by your PC. Generally, you need to re-factor your code to make it embedded-profile compatible.

Comment: I uploaded the whole code. As you can see, there are not functions or other things outside of the embedded-profile...